# Accuracy of CVX solvers

Tags: cvx

I have read in the CVX manual that CVX solvers can efficiency solve some optimization problems to an arbitrary accuracy. I do not understand what arbitrary accuracy means? What it depends on? How we can control it?

Any ideas/hints on where to read to understand more will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CVX solver will iterate a number of times until the desired accuracy (or rather precision) is achieved. The result as found by the CVX solver is then within a certain range of the solution.

Arbitrary accuracy means that you can set the precision you need i.e how close the result has to be to the actual solution. To achieve a better precision will take more time because the CVX solver has to perform more iterations to get closer to the actual solution.

See the associated section about [precision](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/solver.html#controlling-precision) in the [CVX User Manual](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/).

The relevant parts are:

> Numerical methods for convex optimization are not exact; they compute their results to within a predefined numerical precision or tolerance.

and:

> If you wish to modify the tolerances, you may do so using the `cvx_precision` command.